# how to destroy thread in Java without using destroy() method?

Tags: java, sql, multithreading

How can I destroy such a thread that perform very long operation?

I need to solve this problem without setting timeouts for SQL query. I know that `Thread.destroy()` is deprecated.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager
                            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
                    conn.createStatement().execute("SELECT * FROM some_table");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Setting the timeout *is* the best way to do this. *Why* can't you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon is right, setting timeouts is the correct way to resolve the problem.

However, you could have another thread in the background running as a timer which holds a reference to the thread and fires an interrupt. This is effectively a home-grown timeout though!

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts are your best choice here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: actually setting the timeout on the query is **"the best choice"**

Comment: "I need to solve this problem without setting timeouts for SQL query"

Comment: an ill advised arbitrary requirement doesn't change what the **the best choice** is ... your answer implies it is better than the correct way, which it isn't, regardless of their requirement. **the best** is a very strong qualifier.